# Github/compare: How to diff two different files (different file names, both in HEAD)?

Tags: github, git-diff

Can I use the github `/compare` to display the difference between two different source files in HEAD?

Here is how I do it on the command line with `git diff`:

> `git diff HEAD:docs/tutorial/01-boxed-function-pointers.cpp HEAD:docs/tutorial/02-raw-actors.cpp`

My best guess at the github syntax is the following. But it doesn't work:

https://github.com/RossBencina/Fractorp/compare/HEAD:docs/tutorial/01-boxed-function-pointers.cpp...HEAD:docs/tutorial/02-raw-actors.cpp

I specifically want an on-line pretty-printed HTML render of the diff.

If this can't be done with github, can anyone recommend a third-party website that will render diffs of two arbitrary files hosted on github?

### Edit #1:

Thanks to the answers who recommended https://www.diffchecker.com. However, I need to be able to specify the source files as current HEAD on github. Any third-party tool would need to automatically pull the latest source files from github repo URLs. I notice that http://www.mergely.com can *import* source from URLs. However I am looking for a live view that always uses the latest HEAD.

Thank you.

Comment: Strange that their Git-based wiki supports that ([example](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/wiki/Home/_compare/5c7c1f9226f1451e3cc89cbaa6d98f87dc7857d4...cbf4107e5affc3b9153270758255c5788b289894)).

Answer (score 9):

I sometimes use **Diff Checker** tool on the diffchecker website. It is an online diff tool to compare text differences between two text files.

Link: https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: Thanks, but I need something that dynamically pulls the latest sources from github. I've updated the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 8):

### The Situation

On my DevOps team, it is very common to need to create new infrastructure resources (via Infrastructure As Code) which closely resembles existing infrastructure but with just a few changes. When a GitHub "Pull Request is received, the code reviewer is shown thousands of lines of code to ***Review*** and ***Approve***. Even **if they knew** which small portion of the code should be changed, they should feel comfortable assuming "all that other green/new code must have be copied correctly from the correct spot.

I KNOW HOW TO DO THIS VIA THE CLI! But, because we have a workflow that centers around GitHub Enterprise (and **private repos**) my team doesn't use the CLI for this or much of anything.

### The Stopgap Solution

Since [GitHub only accepts points in history for comparisons](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits#comparing-commits) and not paths I have to get clever.

> Assuming FileA is the original and FileB is the modified file at a new path

- Create a temporary branch (using a naming convention like "diff-TICKET-1234")
- Copy FileA on top of FileB
- Commit it
- Push it out to github
- In the last commit message in the branch that is getting a PR (in this case "TICKET-1234"), add a comment:

  - `See: https://github.com/org_name/repo_name/compare/diff-TICKET-1234..TICKET-1234`

Comment: Filing this away under "one weird trick".

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this third party online diff tool for a long time, if you like, you can use it as well. https://www.diffchecker.com. But it seems you should manually paste the two files onto it.

Comment: Thanks, but I need something that dynamically pulls the latest sources from github. I've updated the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[Line Diff](http://linediff.com/) will display a github like diff between two code snippets, however you won't be able to specify the source files as current HEAD on github - I just think it's an edge case and no one has yet thought of making it a "feature" in one of these online tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cheat-y, and you should look into the "premium" options: Hitting a [DiffNow](https://www.diffnow.com/) endpoint will give you a JSONp callback with the name of a temporary HTML file containing a diff.

```
https://www.diffnow.com/EdpProcess.aspx?action=compareUrls&url1=https%3a//raw.githubusercontent.com/RossBencina/Fractorp/master/docs/implementing-tutorial/01-boxed-function-pointers.cpp&url2=https%3a//raw.githubusercontent.com/RossBencina/Fractorp/master/docs/implementing-tutorial/02-raw-actors.cpp
```

Comment: Doesn't work nowadays. They've switched to sending urls via JSON POST.