# GitHub PR To Merge Dev Into Master

Tags: github, pull-request

In a private repo I created a PR to merge changes from dev into master.  The PR shows 168 to be merged automatically - I proceeded with merge and all was ok.

I then created another PR to merge changes from dev to master - I expected 0 files as I had just merged, however it showed the same 168 files, curious I proceeded with the merge and when I looked at the commit, it showed 0 files

[image]

[image]

This wasn't across a fork - just 2 branches in the same repo - can anyone explain why the PR showed 168 files - was this a caching issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the number of files to be merged and actually merged (0) does indeed point out to a cache issue on the remote side.

I would test the caching issue by making the second PR a day after the first, and checking that 0 (or only a few file if you have pushed new commits on `dev`) show up.

If the PR does a three-dots comparison (using the base commit), not that since [Sept. 2018, you can also do, from GitHub, a two-dots comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487289/6309).

See more with:

- "[What are the differences between double-dot “..” and triple-dot “...” in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/6309)"
- "[What are the differences between double-dot “..” and triple-dot “...” in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've been reading a lot about how GitHub build the diff and they use a three-dot diff which would produce the results I'm seeing (https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#three-dot-and-two-dot-git-diff-comparisons).

Comment: @markpirvine True. I have edited the answer with links to GitHub help pages documenting the two vs. three dots diff.

Comment: it seems I need to make a change in my approach to git - either continue to squash merge to master and put up with the three-dot diff, change the url each time to use the two-dot diff (don't see an option to make this the default) or stop squash merging to master...